# Use jquery function .text() to display numbers formatted with .toLocaleString('fr-FR') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, numbers

I have 84000000 and I want to display 84 000 000 in DOM.

```js
var num = 84000000;
$('body').text(num.toLocaleString('fr-FR')); //gives 84000000 but
console.log(num.toLocaleString('fr-FR'));  //gives 84 000 000
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I get this:
[image]
Same thing in all browsers I have.

What is wrong? 
How to show 84 000 000 in DOM using.toLocaleString ?

Comment: I see correctly in both

Comment: I changed the text of the tags on this page, in the console, and get the desired output

Comment: Executing the code spinet shows the correct output!!!

Comment: I am confused. Maybe can this be because i use nodejs? I try 'new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(num);' but I have the same issue. What could be the reason of that please?

Comment: @Cutis You could try using `.html(num.toLocaleString('fr-FR').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));`

Comment: This is my first post about the issues I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948982/tolocalestringfr-fr-not-showing-spaces-in-amount-but-working-in-console/56018982#56018982, could you help to find what is wrong? thanks

Comment: @Cutis I see you are using `replace(/\s/g, '')` which will fully remove all the spaces. Use `.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;')` instead.

Comment: I use replace(/\s/g, '') in order to be able to do some calculations with the amount. After this, I need to "format" to better showing the results to users.

Answer (score 0):

```html
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
         var num = 84000000;
         let strr = num.toLocaleString('fr-FR');
         let output=""
            for(i=0;i<strr.length;i++){
              if(strr[i].charCodeAt(0) == 8239)
                output+=" ";
               else output+=strr[i]
            }
            console.log(output);
            $('body').text(output); 

        </script>
```